# In Excel how do I arrange for the value of a cell to change based on the value of another where I need more options than an IF function

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I am creating a spreadsheet to make it easier to calculate an end figure.

If cell A1 = X value, I want cell A2 to change according to the value of A1,

So, if A1 reads as £100K, I want A2 to read as 0.1, if it reads as £200K I want A2 to read as 0.2 and so on. I have this in a table, but don't know to integrate it.

Comment: Please show some sample data including what you would like to achieve. There are many ways to achieve your example and IF() is one of them. We need more information in order to answer this questions properly.

Comment: sounds like you want some kind of lookup formula

Comment: This is very clear to you, but for people who aren't looking at your spreadsheet or familiar with your task, it is very ambiguous.  The right solution depends on a lot of details you don't cover.  Please provide a complete example of what you need to do.  It would also help if you describe the context of what you're doing.

Comment: `=A1/1000000`?  Is the text in A1 `100000` or is it literally `£100K`?  Perhaps `=TRIM(MID(A2,2,SEARCH("K",A2)-2))/1000` if it's literally the text...

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether **A1** contains a *Number* or a *String* value.  If **A1** contains a *Number*, then in **A2** enter:

```
=A1/10^6
```

and apply the correct formatting, but if **A1** contains a *String* value, then in **A2** enter:

```
="0." & MID(A1,2,1)
```

If you want a formula that will work either way, then use:

```
=IFERROR(A1/10^6,"0."&MID(A1,2,1))
```